# Firebase Auth subscription

Tags: firebase, subscription

I'm working on a app which uses Firebase Auth to signup and login, but I'm facing some things which I don't know how to start. Users need to registrate on a website and they need to pay a subscription before the user is created in firebase, when they don't pay anymore, the user account should be disabled. So basically, users registrate on the web and after they pay, they can log into the app with their credentials.

Edit:

Since yesterday I'm trying to implement either mollie or stripe, but I can't get myself started, online there are very few video's about payments in combination with firebase

Comment: Hi Jelle, I have the same question. Want to make a app with FireBase backend. Also would like to use a subscription model. The user is only allowed to use the app if the user has payed. Can we contact somehow to talk this over?

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways off the top of my headto do this:
A) Secure but it involves cloud function and creating custom authentication token to login.

1. User registers with email.
2. User keys in login information and posts to cloud function.
3. Find user's uid/email and check for password.
4. Fetch the subscription document and check if it is active.
5. If it is inactive, return an error message accordingly.
6. If it is active, create an authentication token and return to user to login.

B) Client side checking, less secure but will do the trick.

1. User logins
2. Fetch subscription using user's uid. Check its validity
3. Force redirect user to subscription page if it is inactive with
   error message. OR Autologout user if it is inactive with error message.

May I also suggest [Stripe](https://stripe.com/en-gb-my/billing) for their subscription service (Not sponsored)? Unless you already have an implementation in place.

Comment: The auto logout is maybe a better idea then disabling the account, what I first thought of. I saw stripe and they have a great collaboration with firebase, but only the creditcard option. The app has a dutch audience and in the Netherlands it is not really so common to have a credit card, so I'm currently checking out the API from Mollie. But I like the idea to auto logout!